# AndroidRuntime: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "0_id"

Tags: android, sqlite

Exception

```
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "0_id": , while compiling: SELECT _id, display_name, photo_id, contacts_status_updates.status_icon AS contact_status_icon, contacts_status_updates.status AS contact_status, agg_presence.mode AS contact_presence, photo_uri FROM view_contacts LEFT OUTER JOIN agg_presence ON (_id = agg_presence.presence_contact_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN status_updates contacts_status_updates ON (status_update_id=contacts_status_updates.status_update_data_id) WHERE (view_contacts.[single_is_restricted] = 0_id IN (SELECT contact_id FROM raw_contacts WHERE raw_contacts._id IN (SELECT data.raw_contact_id FROM data JOIN mimetypes ON (data.mimetype_id = mimetypes._id) WHERE mimetype_id=? AND data1=(SELECT groups._id FROM groups WHERE title=?)))) ORDER BY display_name ASC
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:358)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:321)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at com.coperator.utils.contacts.ContactsUtils5.getContactsByGroup(ContactsUtils5.java:506)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at com.coperator.utils.contacts.ContactsUtils5.getCSipPhonesByGroup(ContactsUtils5.java:521)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at com.coperator.service.PresenceManager.getBuddiesForAccount(PresenceManager.java:61)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at com.coperator.service.PresenceManager.addBuddiesForAccount(PresenceManager.java:74)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at com.coperator.service.PresenceManager.updateRegistrations(PresenceManager.java:188)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at com.coperator.service.PresenceManager.access$0(PresenceManager.java:138)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at com.coperator.service.PresenceManager$AccountStatusContentObserver.onChange(PresenceManager.java:202)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:43)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4464)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:589)
04-12 16:05:16.170: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code

```
@Override
    public Cursor getContactsByGroup(Context ctxt, String groupName) {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(groupName)) {
            return null;
        }

        String[] projection;
        if (Compatibility.isCompatible(11)) {
            projection = new String[] {
                    Contacts._ID,
                    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
                    Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS_ICON,
                    Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS,
                    Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE,
                    Contacts.PHOTO_URI
            };
        } else {
            projection = new String[] {
                    Contacts._ID,
                    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
                    Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS,
                    Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE
            };
        }

        Uri searchUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_GROUP_URI, Uri.encode(groupName));

        return ctxt.getContentResolver().query(searchUri, projection, null, null,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    }
```

Comment: Which Android implementation? One from LG?

Comment: Year~  The error is using the LG with test.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the contacts provider implementation of certain LG phones.
There's nothing you can do in software.

Try to get an update for that phone, or throw the phone away.